# What does * in front of = mean?

Tags: java, logic, assign

Hello everyone I have a very simple question that I just don't understand. I've tried googling it but haven't found a clear answer.

What is x after the following statements?

```
int x = 2;
int y = 1;
x *= y + 1;
```

I know that the answer is 4 but I don't understand why it is 4. Just need some clarity on what x* means exactly. Thanks!

Comment: `x = x * y + 1`. `x = 2 * 1 + 1`. `x = 2 * 2`. `x = 4`

Comment: If you know what `x += y` means, then `x -= y`, `x *= y`, `x /= y`, and `x %= y` should all be intuitive. See [Compound assignment operators in Java](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/compound-assignment-operators-java/)

Answer (score 2):

I think this line is the one why you ask

```
x *= y + 1;
```

This is a shorthand for

```
x = x * (y + 1);
```

This works also with other operators like - and +, when the first variable is the same as the variable on the left side (which will be assigned).

Answer (score 0):

The `x*=` symbol means `x=x*` the result of whatever you put after the equals symbol.

`x*= y+1` will turn to `x = x * (y+1)`. The expresion you put after equals is evaluated first and then multiplied with x. The result will be cast to the type of the assignment variable (x).

Comment: Actually, it doesn't mean that.  1) there is a typecast, 2) you are ignoring operator precedence.  In fact, `x *= <expr>;` really means `x = (<type.of.x>)(x * (<expr>));`.  And yes, there are situations where the typecast and/or precedence **will** matter.

Comment: @StephenC updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Of course x is 4, if you don't understand the last statement, you can read it like this

```
x = x * y + 2
```